How can I override the logging property of a specific package in spring boot?
I understand that i am able to set the logging level as follows:
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.com.mypackage=TRACE

I want to have trace logging enabled on my local environment but i have a rather noisy package that i want to override. Is it possible to set the parent package as TRACE but set a child package as INFO?
I tried it like this but it doesn't seem to work
logging.level.com.mypackage=TRACE
logging.level.com.mypackage.noisy=INFO


Can you set noisy to INFO without setting the parent package as TRACE?

I have tried it out and it works for me. Spring Boot 3.3.0. Check you properties for any misspelling.
